# Problems recover an XVA Virtual Image from XenServer 6.0.2?

Tags: linux, xenserver

I had some backup images created for the VMs (virtual machines) that run on a XenServer 6.0.2. Those images were created using a software called Alike https://xenappblog.com/2013/alike-backup/. When I tried to restore the images in a new server, the XenCenter show the error file data truncated and fails. 
I tried to install the latest version of Alike software 4.6.1, however, I think there not support is not for Windows10. I got this error. Unhandled exception. Error creating query INSERT INTO Schedule. I tried other to version 3.5 and 3.0.8; without any success. I tried this method to convert the images to vmware http://didyourestart.blogspot.com.au/2013/03/convert-xenserver-xva-to-vmdk-for.html?m=1. But it also fail.

Can anyone help me, how can I restore those images.

Comment: Have you contacted [Alike Support](http://www.quadricsoftware.com/support/contact-support/)?

Comment: Yes. They said that could be antivirus that is blocking the images import into Xenserver. I uninstall the antivirus and tried again. Without any success. The support does not really solve anything for me.